# no visible @interface for 'SPTAuth'

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface, spotify

I'm doing my best to develop a Spotify based app that will stream entire tracks for Premium Spotify Members and Partial tracks for Free members.  I'm initializing the Auth process in my appdelegate.m and getting this message "no visible @interface for 'SPTAuth' for loginURLForClientID". Here's the Spotify sample code I'm working from.

```
#import <Spotify/Spotify.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"


// Constants
static NSString * const kClientId = @"Your-Client-Id";
static NSString * const kCallbackURL = @"Your-Callback-URL";
static NSString * const kTokenSwapServiceURL = @"http://localhost:1234/swap";

@interface AppDelegate () <SPTAuthViewDelegate>


@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Create SPTAuth instance; create login URL and open it
    SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
    NSURL *loginURL = [auth loginURLForClientId:kClientId
                            declaredRedirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kCallbackURL]
                                         scopes:@[SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope]];
```

I'm getting the error at [auth loginURLForClientID].  I've tried adding SPTAuth to my @interface, but may be doing it wrong? I don't know.  Please help.  Also....I've tried this with Swift and got similar error.

Comment: Because Spotify had removed this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try these code this will work in new Spotify SDK:

```
SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
auth.clientID = @kSpotifyClientId;
auth.requestedScopes =  @[SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope,SPTAuthStreamingScope,SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope,SPTAuthUserReadEmailScope,SPTAuthUserLibraryModifyScope,SPTAuthUserLibraryReadScope,SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope,SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope];

auth.redirectURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@kCallbackURL];
#ifdef kTokenSwapServiceURL
auth.tokenSwapURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@kTokenSwapServiceURL];
#endif
#ifdef kTokenRefreshServiceURL
auth.tokenRefreshURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@kTokenRefreshServiceURL];
#endif
auth.sessionUserDefaultsKey = kSessionUserDefaultsKey;
```